# Get FormDigest via application page for SharePoint 2013 App

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

The default.aspx page created when starting a new SharePoint App is not needing my needs since it inherits from the host web master page and I have found it easier to obtain a responsive design with my own index.aspx page that has less complexity. Using this article [JSOM in HTML5 Apps](http://allthatjs.com/2012/04/03/using-sharepoint-csom-in-html5-apps/), I am attempting to retrieve the FormDigest, but upon code inspection it is not working. Any ideas? Here is my current code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%--Declare the Page Language and obtain the SharePoint namespace required for retrieving the FormDigest header--%> 
<%@ Page language="C#" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

<title></title>
<link href="../Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<link href="../Content/App.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/1033/init.js"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/MicrosoftAjax.js"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/sp.core.js"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/15/sp.js"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/15/SP.RequestExecutor.js"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/15/SP.UI.Controls.js"></script>

<script src="../Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>

<script src="../Scripts/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/angular-resource.min.js"></script>

<script src="../Scripts/dirPagination.js"></script>

<script src="../Services/services.js"></script>
<script src="../Controllers/controllers.js"></script>
<script src="../App.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<SharePoint:FormDigest ID="FormDigest1" runat="server"></SharePoint:FormDigest>
 <div class="container" data-ng-app="app">
      <div id="chrome_ctrl_container"></div>
    <div>
        <p id="message">

            initializing...
        </p>
    </div>
    <div data-ng-view></div>
    <hr>
    <footer></footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have discovered that I needed a form instance to execute the call. Its working perfectly:

index.aspx

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%--Declare the Page Language and obtain the SharePoint namespace required for retrieving the FormDigest header--%> 
<%@ Page language="C#" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

<title></title>
<link href="../Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<link href="../Content/App.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/1033/init.js"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/MicrosoftAjax.js"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/sp.core.js"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/15/sp.js"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/15/SP.RequestExecutor.js"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/15/SP.UI.Controls.js"></script>

<script src="../Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>

<script src="../Scripts/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/angular-resource.min.js"></script>

<script src="../Scripts/dirPagination.js"></script>

<script src="../Services/services.js"></script>
<script src="../Controllers/controllers.js"></script>
<script src="../App.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<%--    Get the form digest to use for POST/Update/Delete operations via Web services--%>
<form id="Form1" method="post" runat="server">
<SharePoint:FormDigest ID="FormDigest1" runat="server"></SharePoint:FormDigest>
    </form>
 <div class="container" data-ng-app="app">
      <div id="chrome_ctrl_container"></div>
    <div>
        <p id="message">

            initializing...
        </p>
    </div>
    <div data-ng-view></div>
    <hr>
    <footer></footer>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Example of us in ngResource call via AngularJS:

```
appServices.factory('appTypes', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    return $resource("/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Todo Types List')/Items", {Id: "@Id"},
    {
        'query': { method: "GET", isArray: false, headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json;odata=nometadata' } },
        'update': { method: 'PATCH', headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json;odata=nometadata' } },
        'save': { method: 'POST', headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json;odata=nometadata', 'content-type': 'application/json;odata=nometadata', 'X-RequestDigest': $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val() } }
    }
    );
}]);
```